# How do I install the openCV library for the Arduino IDE?

Tags: c++, opencv, arduino, processing

I am working on an Arduino project that uses facial tracking, object tracking, facial recognition etc. To accomplish this, I decided to use the OpenCV library. The problem is, however, I don't know how to install the OpenCV library for Arduino, and Processing. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the Processing Editor:

Go to the **Sketch** menu, then select **Import Library...* and then go to **Add Library...**

That brings up the **Contribution Manager** where you can search for Processing libraries. Search for **OpenCV for Processing**, select it, and click the **Install** button.

Once it's installed, import it into your sketch to use it.

More info can be found [here](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/).