# I downloaded the OpenCV library for Processing, but can't run the examples

Tags: opencv, processing

I downloaded the OpenCV library for Processing as per the advice of the question I asked on this post: [How do I install the openCV library for the Arduino IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853977/how-do-i-install-the-opencv-library-for-the-arduino-ide)

However, I can't run any of the example programs except the "LiveCamTest" example. On any other example such as this:

```
import gab.opencv.*;

PImage src, dst;
OpenCV opencv;

ArrayList<Contour> contours;
ArrayList<Contour> polygons;

void setup() {
  src = loadImage("test.jpg"); 
  size(src.width, src.height/2);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, src);

  opencv.gray();
  opencv.threshold(70);
  dst = opencv.getOutput();

  contours = opencv.findContours();
  println("found " + contours.size() + " contours");
}

void draw() {
  scale(0.5);
  image(src, 0, 0);
  image(dst, src.width, 0);

  noFill();
  strokeWeight(3);

  for (Contour contour : contours) {
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    contour.draw();

    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    beginShape();
    for (PVector point : contour.getPolygonApproximation().getPoints()) {
      vertex(point.x, point.y);
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

I get the error: The size of this sketch could not be determined from your code.
Can anyone tell me how to get these to examples to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the `size()` function with variables from the `setup()` function. So this won't work:

```
void setup() {
  src = loadImage("test.jpg"); 
  size(src.width, src.height/2);
```

You can't base a sketch off of an image size like that. You need to use hard-coded values instead.

You might also want to look into the `settings()` function that was added in Processing 3. From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html):

> The `settings()` function is new with Processing 3.0. It's not needed in most sketches. It's only useful when it's absolutely necessary to define the parameters to `size()` with a variable. Alternately, the `settings()` function is necessary when using Processing code outside of the Processing Development Environment (PDE). For example, when using the Eclipse code editor, it's necessary to use `settings()` to define the `size()` and `smooth()` values for a sketch..
>
> The `settings()` method runs before the sketch has been set up, so other Processing functions cannot be used at that point. For instance, do not use `loadImage()` inside `settings()`. The `settings()` method runs "passively" to set a few variables, compared to the `setup()` command that call commands in the Processing API.

By the way, these questions have nothing to do with C++, so you might want to stop tagging them with the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.